# Boto EC2: Create an instance with tags

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, boto

Is there a way with the boto python API to specify tags when creating an instance? I'm trying to avoid having to create an instance, fetch it and then add tags. It would be much easier to have the instance either pre-configured to have certain tags or to specify tags when I execute the following command:

```
ec2server.create_instance(
        ec2_conn, ami_name, security_group, instance_type_name, key_pair_name, user_data
    )
```

Comment: You indeed can assign tags at instance create time - see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43723682/4988742

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This answer was accurate at the time it was written but is now out of date. The AWS API's and Libraries (such as boto3) can now take a "TagSpecification" parameter that allows you to specify tags when running the "create_instances" call.

---

Tags cannot be made until the instance has been created. Even though the function is called create_instance, what it's really doing is reserving and instance. Then that instance may or may not be launched. (Usually it is, but sometimes...)

So, you cannot add a tag until it's been launched. And there's no way to tell if it's been launched without polling for it. Like so:

```
reservation = conn.run_instances( ... )

# NOTE: this isn't ideal, and assumes you're reserving one instance. Use a for loop, ideally.
instance = reservation.instances[0]

# Check up on its status every so often
status = instance.update()
while status == 'pending':
    time.sleep(10)
    status = instance.update()

if status == 'running':
    instance.add_tag("Name","{{INSERT NAME}}")
else:
    print('Instance status: ' + status)
    return None

# Now that the status is running, it's not yet launched. The only way to tell if it's fully up is to try to SSH in.
if status == "running":
    retry = True
    while retry:
        try:
            # SSH into the box here. I personally use fabric
            retry = False
        except:
            time.sleep(10)

# If we've reached this point, the instance is up and running, and we can SSH and do as we will with it. Or, there never was an instance to begin with.
```

Comment: A supplement to this solution might be to use [conn.create_tags(instance_id_list,tag_dict)](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.create_tags) which allows you to add multiple tags to multiple (already created!) instances with one command.

Comment: The polling loop isn't necessary; you can set tags while an instance is still in the `pending` status.

Comment: I want to add to @ChrisMartin comment: You really don't want to wait for the instance to be running before adding tags; you want to add them ASAP, because if you have cloud-init or user-data scripts that act on the values of tags, you want to make sure the tags are there before these startup scripts run.

Comment: This is outdated answer. You indeed can assign tags at instance create time - see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43723682/4988742

Answer (score 14):

[You can tag instance or volume on creation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_TagSpecification.html)

From [run_instances docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html):

> You can tag instances and EBS volumes during launch, after launch, or both. For more information, see [CreateTags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTags.html) and [Tagging Your Amazon EC2 Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html).

[Using Tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) AWS doc includes a table with resources supporting tagging and supporting tagging on creation (Instance and EBS Volume support both as of 01-MAY-2017)

Here is a code snippet to tag instance at creation time in Python (other SDK references are listed on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_TagSpecification.html)):

```
from pkg_resources import parse_version
import boto3
assert parse_version(boto3.__version__) >= parse_version('1.4.4'), \
    "Older version of boto3 installed {} which doesn't support instance tagging on creation. Update with command 'pip install -U boto3>=1.4.4'".format(boto3.__version__)
import botocore
assert parse_version(botocore.__version__) >= parse_version('1.5.63'), \
   "Older version of botocore installed {} which doesn't support instance tagging on creation. Update with command 'pip install -U botocore>=1.5.63'".format(botocore.__version__)
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
tag_purpose_test = {"Key": "Purpose", "Value": "Test"}
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId=EC2_IMAGE_ID,
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType=EC2_INSTANCE_TYPE,
    KeyName=EC2_KEY_NAME,
    SecurityGroupIds=[EC2_DEFAULT_SEC_GROUP],
    SubnetId=EC2_SUBNET_ID,
    TagSpecifications=[{'ResourceType': 'instance',
                        'Tags': [tag_purpose_test]}])[0]
```

I used

```
Python 2.7.13
boto3 (1.4.4)
botocore (1.5.63)
```

Comment: `'Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input: "TagSpecifications", must be one of: DryRun, ImageId, MinCount...`

Comment: @Zulu could you share your code snippet and the libs versions?
Wonder if API definitions changed with newer libs versions.

Comment: @Zulu you definitely have older version of boto3. I see older boto3 does not support TagSpecifications for create_instances function.
update your boto3: pip install -U boto3>=1.4.4 and retry.

Comment: Got the same error (`Unknown parameter in input: "TagSpecifications"`), and I am using Boto3 1.4.4. The same code was working few months ago, so I think they might have changed something in the AWS side. I see that TagSpecifications are mentioned in the docs (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) though.

Comment: @np8 could you share a snippet of your code? Have you tried to just use AWS-CLI? (also check installed version)
Wonder what other differences could cause the difference...
I only ran into your issue with older boto3 version.

Comment: @np8 also make sure your `botocore >= 1.5.63` (latest is 1.5.83)

Comment: I tried with botocore 1.5.84, and got no errors. Thanks!

Comment: @np8 yay! glad to help

Comment: @Zulu.. I have added tag for volume snapshot, but keep raising 'is not a valid taggable resource type for this operation.' I have tried volid, where it is variable contains actual volid, also snap, but all with similar error. Below is the one with volid as resourceType  snap=ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId=volid,Description=instancename+"/"+instanceid+"/"+volid,DryRun=False,TagSpecifications=[{'ResourceType':volid, 'Tags':[vol_name_tag]}])

Answer (score 3):

Using boto 2.9.6, I'm able to add tags to an instance immediately after getting my response back from run_instances. Something like this works without sleep:

```
reservation = my_connection.run_instances(...)
for instance in reservation.instances:
    instance.add_tag('Name', <whatever>)
```

I verified that the instance was still in pending state after successfully adding the tag. It would be easy to wrap this logic in a function similar to that requested by the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This method has worked for me:

```
rsvn = image.run(
  ... standard options ...
)

sleep(1)

for instance in rsvn.instances:
   instance.add_tag('<tag name>', <tag value>)
```

Comment: yeah, that's what my code currently has to do, but as the question stated, I'm looking for a way to either pre-configure tags, or include them in the create_instance command.

Comment: @stevebot Why? In what way is this method insufficient?

Comment: You have a sleep(1) which I am assuming is so the instance will boot up and be configured. What if this never happens or takes longer? This means more code.It would be much nicer to have the configuration already taken care of and not have to worry about stalled instances in this case.

Comment: @ZackBloom, stevebot is right, this snippet depends on the instance launching within a fixed time period.

Comment: The elephant in the room here is that organizations need to be able to restrict which set of resources a given person can control and they want to do this via EC2 resource-level tagging. However, to tag an EC2 instance with 'dev' you need to do it *after* launch and that means you need to have permission to create/modify tags. If you have those permissions then you can effectively bypass any tag-based restrictions. An unfortunate Catch-22.

Comment: Yes I did something similar but with a loop waiting for the status of the instance to be 'running'. However a way to do it within the run_instances() is what I am after.